# add color to HTML Menu

Tags: html, css

I have this code for a side menu, as you can see it is all white.

How do I make each tab a different color?

see my code

```css
.navigation {
  width: 300px
}

.mainmenu,
.submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.mainmenu a,
.mainmenu label {
  display: block;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 18px;
  color: #000
}

.mainmenu input {
  display: none
}

.mainmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #c5c5c5
}

.mainmenu :checked+.submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 900px
}

.submenu a {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #993
}

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">

  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="0" title="0">0</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="AFazenda 11"> A</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">C</a></li>
    <li><label for="products">1</label><input type="checkbox" id="products" />
      <ul class="submenu" itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement'>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'> </a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'><a href='' itemprop='url'> I</a></li>
        <li itemprop='name'><a href='' itemprop='url'> II</a></li>
        <li itemprop='name'><a href='' itemprop='url'> III</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>


  </ul>
</nav>
```

I would like to leave the menus and sub menus each 1 with 1 different color.

Comment: Please format your code. No-one likes horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I can't format, when I try to get a message saying for more details

Comment: Whenever I try to format a question code I get a message that to save I need to give more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class or ID to each of the `<li>`s or use the `nth-child()` selector as follows:

```css
.navigation {
  width: 300px
}

.mainmenu,
.submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.mainmenu a,
.mainmenu label {
  display: block;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 18px;
  color: #000
}

.mainmenu input {
  display: none
}

.mainmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #c5c5c5
}

.mainmenu :checked+.submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 900px
}

.submenu a {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #993
}

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out
}
.mainmenu>li:nth-child(1) a {
    background-color: red;
}
.mainmenu>li:nth-child(2) a {
    background-color: orange;
}
.mainmenu>li:nth-child(3) a {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.mainmenu>li:nth-child(4) a {
    background-color: green;
}
.mainmenu>li:nth-child(5) a {
    background-color: blue;
}
.mainmenu>li:nth-child(6) a {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">

  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="0" title="0">0</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="AFazenda 11"> A</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">C</a></li>
    <li><label for="products">1</label><input type="checkbox" id="products" />
      <ul class="submenu" itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement'>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'> </a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'>
          <a href='' itemprop='url'></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop='name'><a href='' itemprop='url'> I</a></li>
        <li itemprop='name'><a href='' itemprop='url'> II</a></li>
        <li itemprop='name'><a href='' itemprop='url'> III</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>


  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Edit:** For a second menu with the class `mainmenu2`, just add it to your color rules:

```
.mainmenu>li:nth-child(1) a,
.mainmenu2>li:nth-child(1) a {
    background-color: red;
}
.mainmenu>li:nth-child(2) a,
.mainmenu2>li:nth-child(2) a {
    background-color: orange;
}
.mainmenu>li:nth-child(3) a,
.mainmenu2>li:nth-child(3) a {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.mainmenu>li:nth-child(4) a,
.mainmenu2>li:nth-child(4) a {
    background-color: green;
}
.mainmenu>li:nth-child(5) a,
.mainmenu2>li:nth-child(5) a {
    background-color: blue;
}
.mainmenu>li:nth-child(6) a,
.mainmenu2>li:nth-child(6) a {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: One question, if I make two separate menus, will the css of 1 be applied to the other?

Comment: sorry for the question, just need to change class = "mainmenu" and css to class = "mainmenu2"

Comment: I am trying to change the color of the word to white and leave it highlighted but the effect does not appear. Is it a mistake in the code?

Comment: Do me a favor, go to jsfiddle.net and make a working example there of what you have so far, then give me the link and I'll help you get it sorted out.

Comment: Sorry again, I edited the wrong code, now it's working fine

Comment: Do you know how I can make the effect hover?

Comment: Sure, just add the `:hover` pseudo-selector, for instance `.mainmenu>li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}`